# Data Migration in PL/SQL with Toad

Tags: oracle, plsql, etl, toad

I am beginner on PL/SQL, and I have to use it for data migration.

We are setting up a new Human Resources Management system. So, we want to:

- Extract all data of the old system
- Edit it with PL/SQL
- Export it in XML files (another team gonna load the XML files to the new system after that)

We have to edit column names, column types, employees IDs, etc.. in a way that all data can be suitable for the new system.

Can anyone explain me steps to do this, show me links or similar examples.

Comment: what is the existing database used before the migration to PL/SQL?

Comment: if you are using sql server 

please see this link
https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/hol08/sqldev_migration/mssqlserver/migrate_microsoft_sqlserver_otn.htm

Comment: hi, I would suggest export data as CSV files and use a scripting language to convert CSV  to XML file. so you might have good flexibility. like DB-->CSV file -->XML file

Comment: hi, you can read many link , check this one https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:3512822500346787661

Comment: Is the target (new) database also an Oracle database?

Comment: We will extract data from an oracle database and the target database is an oracle database also

Answer (score 0):

**This answer is keeping in mind that you are using a oracle data base to extract data and create xml files**

For extracting data from database tables to xml you have several options

1. Using Sql

Example:-

> ```
> SELECT XMLElement( "DEPARTMENT"
>                  , department_name
>                  )
>   FROM departments
>  WHERE department_id IN (10, 20);
> ```

output

```
<DEPARTMENT>Administration</DEPARTMENT> <DEPARTMENT>Marketing</DEPARTMENT>
```

2.Using PLSQL

- using plsql XMLTYPE constructor
- using DBMS_XMLGEN package
- using dbms_xmldom package

With the XMLTYPE constructor and DBMS_XMLGEN package, you can create simple XML documents, fast and easy. When you need to create more advanced XML documents or want to have more control on how your XML document looks like, DBMS_XMLDOM can be used. The DBMS_XMLDOM package is a bit more complicated as you’ll have to create the entire document by calling functions and procedures of the package.

Refer following 2 articles

[Generating XML from SQL and PL/SQL – Part 1](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/oracle/generating-xml-from-sql-and-pl-sql-part-1/)

[Generating XML from SQL and PL/SQL – Part 2](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/oracle/generating-xml-from-sql-and-plsql-part-2/)

To Wite the xml in to a file you can use

- Oracle ***Spool*** if you are using sql to generate
- xml ***UTL_FILE*** package if you are using plsql to generate xml

Comment: Thanks Dimuthu, but the problem is not in data extraction, it's in data transformation. I have to modify columns types, labels of Countries, etc .. in between

Comment: This is not only for data extraction only. But if you take a close look at those examples you can transform the old column names to new columns names (to be in the Xml for the new system) If you have the mapping between old database and new databse columns its just a matter of writing the logic in given way in those examples.
Suggest you to use dbms_xmldom package